# Importing Data from github using Python in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the book "Hands-on machine learning with scikit-learn and tensorflow" by Aurelien Geron.

It's my first time using Jupyter.

I'm trying to follow the following code.
[image]

My problem is when I run the cell with this code:

```
import os
import tarfile
import urllib
DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok=True)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
```

The cell evaluation never ends, with the `In[*]:` never becoming something like `In[1]:`.

So, I thought it was a problem with the initial url, because it showed an error when I visited it through my internet browser.

Hence, I changed it to `DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/tree/master/"`.

Now I get `In[1]:`. However, when I run `fetch_housing_data()`, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReadError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bd66b1fe6daf> in <module>
----> 1 fetch_housing_data()

<ipython-input-5-ef3c39b342d8> in fetch_housing_data(housing_url, housing_path)
      9     tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
     10     urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
---> 11     housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
     12     housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
     13     housing_tgz.close()

~\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py in open(cls, name, mode, fileobj, bufsize, **kwargs)
   1576                         fileobj.seek(saved_pos)
   1577                     continue
-> 1578             raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
   1579 
   1580         elif ":" in mode:

ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Why does this happen, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you restarted your kernel and tried running again?
What you are seeing isn't reproducible.

The first code block you pasted above works as written. No need to modify it.
I just ran this below and then when I ran `fetch_housing_data()` in another cell it worked:

```py
import os
import tarfile
import urllib
DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok=True)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
```

You sure it isn't just an artifact that you don't see the cell completing?
If you want to independently verify, you can run it elsewhere like I did. I just tested it by going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila) and pressing the bottom `launch binder` link. Then I pasted your code in a cell that comes up. After running those two cells, I have a directory at `/home/jovyan/scripts/datasets/housing` with the contents `housing.csv  housing.tgz`.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for the help. I ran the code again, and it now works... I have no idea why it didn't work. Maybe it was because I had installed Anaconda for the first time ever, without rebooting my system. I don't know... thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Specify the URL of the raw CSV file on GitHub
csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nghait/gpt/main/AIGPTDAT.csv'

# Read the CSV file from the URL into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(csv_url, sep=';')

# Now you can work with the DataFrame
# For example, you can print the first few rows
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score -2):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/

I am not sure what kind of a link this is. Maybe someone can explain. When I just type in this link, I cannot access the page. However it does work for retrieving the data which I explained in the next praragraph. If I use the actual github link https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/tree/master/ that you mentioned above, the code is unable to extract the data.

I have been able to extract the csv file from the link using the steps in the book by adding another line in the 'imports'. I added "import urllib.request". This seems to work for me on Google Colab. Importing urllib you would think that urllib.request is also imported but that's not the case. I cannot answer why it is working but documentation for urllib had 'import urllib.request' in one example and I took the idea.